# JMeter GRPC Sampler OutOfMemoryError

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, grpc, jmeter-plugins, grpc-java

Has anybody already worked with the zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-plugin / Apache License 2.0 GRPC Sampler for JMeter?
The following problem occurs while testing e.g. 100 quick requests which lead to 2MB payload size per response. I have no idea how to solve it. The more data was send the earlier the issue occurs.

`Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Generate Summary Results +     50 in 00:00:11 =    4.6/s Avg:   188 Min:   129 Max:  1435 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
Generate Summary Results +     50 in 00:00:08 =    6.6/s Avg:   148 Min:   127 Max:   227 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 1 Finished: 1
Generate Summary Results =    100 in 00:00:18 =    5.4/s Avg:   168 Min:   127 Max:  1435 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Generate Summary Results +      1 in 00:00:01 =    0.7/s Avg:  1043 Min:  1043 Max:  1043 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid10268.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [1085958721 bytes in 2.412 secs]
Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]. See log file for details.
Generate Summary Results +     40 in 00:00:30 =    1.3/s Avg:   719 Min:   507 Max:  2895 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
Generate Summary Results =     41 in 00:00:32 =    1.3/s Avg:   727 Min:   507 Max:  2895 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Generate Summary Results +     41 in 00:00:30 =    1.4/s Avg:   681 Min:   505 Max:  1156 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
Generate Summary Results =     82 in 00:01:02 =    1.3/s Avg:   704 Min:   505 Max:  2895 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Generate Summary Results +     18 in 00:00:12 =    1.5/s Avg:   622 Min:   494 Max:   828 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 1 Finished: 1
Generate Summary Results =    100 in 00:01:14 =    1.4/s Avg:   689 Min:   494 Max:  2895 Err:     0 (0.00%)`

Answer (score 0):

[Java heap space OOM error](https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space) means that JVM isn't able to fit all the necessary objects within the define Java Heap space, default setting for the latest JMeter is [1 GB](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter.bat#L151)

If the default setting is not enough you can increase heap like:

- Windows

  ```
  set HEAP="-Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m" && jmeter.bat
  ```
- Unix and derivaties:

  ```
  HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m" && export HEAP && ./jmeter.sh
  ```

to make the changes permanent edit `jmeter.bat` or `jmeter` shell startup script wrappers

The above setting will increase the maximum heap size allocation twice (up to 2 GB), it may or may not be sufficient for your scenario, check whether it works and amend if necessary, just make sure that garbage collection doesn't  occur to often and doesn't take too much time blocking other threads.

More information: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Also looking at `AWT-EventQueue` it seems that you're using JMeter GUI for running the test, if it's the case - please don't, JMeter GUI is for tests development and debugging, tests are supposed to be run in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)